# How to setup wifi params at booting time?

Tags: networking, wireless, configuration

How do I set an automatically configuration for my wifi card at a booting time with these params:

```
sudo iw phy0 set rts 784
sudo iw phy0 set frag 1024
```

Anyone to help?